# Performing calculations with jQuery .val() return values

Tags: jquery, math

Been trying for the past few hours but can't seem to make it work.

I need to calculate the square root of a sum. There seems to exist a javascript method to calculate this (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sqrt.asp) using Math.sqrt(). How can I use this method so that it calculates the square root of my sum? The sum is displayed after you fill in the two input fields and works fine..

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yunowork/zLKgT/) or code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#beers').keyup(calculate);
    $('#ranking').keyup(calculate);

function calculate(e)
{
    $('p#sum').html($('#beers').val() * 5 / $('#ranking').val() + 1); //calculation of the two fields
        /*Math.sqrt()*/ //This is the function to calculate the square root
}
});
```

Comment: Usually you'll want to, you know, _call_ the function.

Comment: @Shmiddty he is. It's bound to two keyup events.

Comment: @Cecchi He's calling `Math.sqrt`? Coulda fooled me.

Comment: I commented the Math.sqrt() part as it was not really clear to me how to call this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is *call* `Math.sqrt` by passing in the number that you want the square-root of: http://jsfiddle.net/zLKgT/2/

```
$('#beers').keyup(calculate);
$('#ranking').keyup(calculate);

function calculate(e) {
    var maths = $('#beers').val() * 5 / $('#ranking').val() + 1;
    $('p#sum').text(maths);
    $('p#squareroot').text(Math.sqrt(maths));
}​
```

You don't need to convert anything to a number before hand because you are using number objects and not using the `+` operator which functions both for addition and concatenation. Javascript will automatically convert the `val`s to numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarification Schmiddty, very helpful. Is there any possible way to round the numbers up to 2 digits after the comma in your example? Something like:     $('p#squareroot').text(Math.sqrt(maths.round(number).toFixed(2))); Sorry for what might be a stupid question, am pretty new to jQuery

Comment: @Yunowork This really has nothing to do with jQuery. It's all standard javascript. But yes, `maths.toFixed(2)` and `Math.sqrt(maths).toFixed(2)` should work. There might be some compatibility issues with certain browsers, though.

Comment: A common alternate method to round is like this: `Math.round(numberToRound*100)/100` will round to 2 decimal places. You can use 10 for one decimal place, 1000 for 3 decimals, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert that to a number 
Because .val() returns a string and you are multiplying two strings here..

Use `parseInt()`  or `parseFloat()` to convert to a number first ..

```
var beers = parseInt($('#beers').val() , 10 );
var rankings =  parseInt($('#ranking').val() , 10 );

var sqrt = Math.sqrt((beers * 5)/ (rankings + 1))

$('p#sum').html(sqrt);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zLKgT/1/)**

Comment: Not really necessary. The values are automatically converted to numbers when he performs the mathematical operation.

Comment: @Shmiddty .. good point .. I just wanted to make more clear.. It is not required but I feel it is a better practice to do so ..

Answer (score 0):

Relevent example to your question, convert it to a number, with the var 'answer' you can display it in html using Jquery or any other way you like

```
var numericFormat = new Number($('#beers').val() * 5 / $('#ranking').val() + 1)
var answer = Math.sqrt(numericFormat);
```

Comment: Javascript automatically converts it to a number.